# Scrapy disable retry middleware

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I commented the line in settings.py but it continues being enabled.

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {  
       #'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 90,
       'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
    }
```

At the start of the program it loads a lot of middlewares I didn't enable

```
2019-08-09 10:43:37 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
```

Am I missing something? Is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, the `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES` [**is merged with `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES_BASE`**](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html). In the latter, the option `scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.RetryMiddleware` is enabled by default.

So either write

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {  
       'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': None,
       #                                                     ^^^
       'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
    }
```

Or look into `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES_BASE`. See [**their documentation for more details**](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std:setting-DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES_BASE).